# Execute Alexa Skill programmatically

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I'm wondering if there's a way to execute an Alexa skill programmatically. Specifically, I want a Raspberry Pi to tell my Alexa device to play a specific song from Amazon Music.

I'm really new to Alexa but the docs I'm reading are all about how to create and manage skills, not call them.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You should try slightly different product from Amazon. It called [Alexa Voice Service](https://developer.amazon.com/alexa/console/avs/home)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking to reuse the logic you already have via voice with Alexa to play your songs and use another way via raspberry pi to control the music. This could help you:

[How can I trigger Alexa intent with clicks rather than voice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55017008/how-can-i-trigger-alexa-intent-with-clicks-rather-than-voice)