# Asking Alexa to do something via REST API call?

Tags: rest, alexa-skills-kit

I am a bit perplexed on how one might ask Alexa how to do something and get a response?  I looked through some of the questions found on Stack Overflow and did some Googling, which only added to the confusion.  After some initial reading, I have seen references to skills (I know of them, that I have used them, but all within the Alexa app), but every result mentions skill building or interfacing, and then talk to the skill?  Not as easy as some others, but not surprised by this given how huge and complex Amazon Alexa universe is.

So, am I making a mountain out of a ant-hill? .. or is there an easy way to setup a token or such in my account and use it to authenticate and perform calls?

If there is a prerequisite reading list or a good website the explains this process.. I would greatly appreciate info from the community.

I found this 3-year-old articles, solution seems kinda clunky, but still digging:
[How can I trigger Alexa intent with clicks rather than voice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55017008/how-can-i-trigger-alexa-intent-with-clicks-rather-than-voice)

Answer (score 0):

If you've already created an Alexa skill, then yes, it's possible to programmatically send an arbitrary JSON message to your skill's back-end Lambda function without the need to speak or interact with a physical Echo device. The way you can achieve this is via the "Skill Messaging API":

https://developer.amazon.com/docs/smapi/skill-messaging-api-reference.html

A successful Skill Messaging API call will result in your Lambda function receiving a [Messaging.MessageReceived](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/custom-skills/messaging-interface-reference.html#request-body-example) request which will contain the JSON you sent to the API endpoint. Your skill's back-end can then process that information as needed.

To be clear though, the one thing you *cannot* do in response to a `Messaging.MessageReceived` request, is wake the Echo device to have it initiate a conversation with the user. Interactions with an Echo device must still begin with a user verbally or physically interacting with the device in question.